# Setting different colours on multiple bars for a bar chart in Python?

Tags: python, bar-chart, sensors

Is it possible to set different colours on multiple bars for a bar chart in Python? I'm trying to show different colours for participant R1 and R2 from a text file structured like this:

```
2009-02-02  07:38:31.220809 M29 OFF
2009-02-02  07:38:31.430629 M37 OFF
2009-02-02  07:38:33.946559 M36 ON  R1_Personal_Hygiene end
2009-02-02  07:44:12.597919 M49 ON  R2_Bed_to_Toilet begin
2009-02-02  07:44:12.74531  M38 OFF
2009-02-02  07:44:12.886409 M46 OFF
2009-02-02  07:44:15.04394  M50 ON
2009-02-02  07:44:15.52659  M44 ON
2009-02-02  07:44:15.88134  M47 OFF
2009-02-02  07:44:16.091619 M47 OFF
2009-02-02  07:44:16.292619 M47 OFF
2009-02-02  07:44:18.04502  M48 OFF
2009-02-02  07:44:18.22705  M49 OFF
2009-02-02  07:44:18.79765  M43 ON
2009-02-02  07:44:20.825139 M28 ON
2009-02-02  07:44:21.16597  M42 ON
```

I am able to hard code it but I'm reading sensor data from a text file line by line and storing it in an array. I think it has to do with the **colour** function, but I don't know how to employ it on my array. This is my code so far:

```
# Import libraries
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

#Get user input
file_name = input('Enter File name: ')
file = open(file_name)
#Array of sensors
sensors = []

#Iterate through the file line by line
for line in file:
    words = line.split()
    #This line filters out the sensor data for the required time 
    interval
    if (datetime.strptime (words[1][0:7], "%H:%M:%S")) > 
    (datetime.strptime ("07:00:00", "%H:%M:%S")) and (datetime.strptime 
    (words[1][0:7], "%H:%M:%S")) < (datetime.strptime ("08:00:00", 
    "%H:%M:%S")):
        if words[3] == "ON":
            sensors.append(words[2])

count = collections.Counter(sensors)
print(count)

# Plot Graph and Set Y labels and X Labels
plt.bar(range(len(count)),count.values(),align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(count)),count.keys())
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.xlabel('Sensors')
plt.title('Motion Sensor Data')
plt.show()
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in your legend:

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
```

And then you just need to figure out how many different colours you want - to be honest, I did not quite get what defines the numebr of colours in your example, hence I will just give a general expression.

```
NrCol = #Enter formula or methode to calculate total number of colours needed 
colour = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0,1,NrCol))
```

This is an colour array and now you can access the colours with an index like this:

```
color = colour[j]
```

I don't get what you want, but if you say that you can hardcode it, you should be able to replace your hardcoded colour with this colour and it should be fine.

Hope that helps! Cheers

Comment: Thanks but what's np?

Comment: oh that is numpy. you need to add import numpy as np to your introduction. Cheers